Straightforward C code takes a long time to run, any methods of optimising it?
I wrote a basic code that utilises a leapfrog integrator (aka kick-drift-kick) to simulate gravitational systems. So far it has worked successfully at simulating orbits in any potential you input.
However, for a proper test-particle simulation I want to increase the particle count to ~1 million, which is where the main issue manifests - it is remarkably slow, approximately 35 minutes for 1 Myr (the timestep at which the simulation progresses is 0.001 Myr, so 1000 steps in a for-loop).
Most of my coding experience is in Python, so my concern is that I missed something key in my C code that slows down the code so significantly. I tested different optimisation methods, like parallelising my time loop so I can integrate more particles at a single time, but that either marginally improved the runtime or non at all.
Below I am pasting the code with all the necessary comments, but I cut down on the code size for this question as some of the potentials I use are very bulky and take up space.
I would be thankful for guidance and suggestions, I want to truly understand how C operates and not limit myself to half-baked code, I might have missed a key C coding practice and added artificial barriers for the code to run fast etc.
Some burning questions are:

Are while-loops are slower than for-loops when performing orbit integration?
Are the if-conditions I use to save particle information are slowing down my code?
Is there a way to create a buffer array to dump particle coordinates/velocities into to save at a later date? I am worried that a 20x1,000,000x7 double array would be too massive to be computational efficient.
If there are no particle-particle interactions to compute, would using OpenMP be considered superfluous or can it still speed up the computations?

Edit: I was unaware how compiling can affect the performance of my code, so I will add this information here: I just compile it with gcc-13 with no other options, unless I was testing OpenMP in which case I added -fopenmp. Which optimizer flags would be best for my code or do I just compile with -O3?
Here is the code
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
// #include <omp.h> //previous experiments, touched on at the end

//Model Parameters

//Halo
const double Mh=2e12; //Mass of halo
const double ah=16e3; //Halo paramter
const double ch=0.53980675319058735; //Halo paramter c=15.3, simplified for formula value

//t_force parameters
const double Mt_f=2.5*3.43*1e10; //Maximum mass
const double R_t=(15*2.5)*1000; // Fixed paramater determining the scale of the potential
const double mdt=2000; //Mass gain rate (units = Myr)

// Units
#define pi 3.141592653589793
#define G 0.00449857598201285

// Sim Setup
const double theta=75*pi/180.; //Inclination of disc, explained further down
const double CCD=1; // Period of file saving, explained further down
const double dt=0.001; //Fixed time step (units = Myr)
const double runtime=4e3; //Total runtime (units = Myr)
const int timelim=runtime/dt; //Integer limit in for-loop
char name[999]="SIMNAME"; //Simulation snapshot name format
//Number of particles
#define pno 1000000

//Norms of vectors norm()
double norm(double x[3])
    {
      return sqrt(x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2]);
    }

// Function that rotates particles around x-axis
void rotate(double x[3],double v[3],double theta)
{
    double yd,zd,vy,vz;
    yd=x[1]*cos(theta)-x[2]*sin(theta);//
    zd=x[1]*sin(theta)+x[2]*cos(theta);//
    x[1]=yd;//
    x[2]=zd;//
    vy=v[1]*cos(theta)-v[2]*sin(theta);
    vz=v[1]*sin(theta)+v[2]*cos(theta);
    v[1]=vy;
    v[2]=vz;
}

//Mass function of t_force - a time dependant potential (only increasing mass, other parameters stay constant)
double Mt(double t)
    {
        double mass;
        if (t<mdt) {mass=Mt_f*t/mdt;}
        else {mass=Mt_f;}
        return mass;
    }

//Calculating force for every particle (only potentials, no particle-particle interactions). h_force is a static potential representing an NFW halo
void calculate_force(double x[3], double a[3], double mt_c)
{
    //Normss
    double md=norm(x);
    //Forces
    double t_force[3]={0.,0.,0.};
    double h_force;
    torus_force_r[0]=((G*mt_c*x[0]*((3*pow(x[2],2))/(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2))-0.5))/pow(R_t,3)-(0.3750*G*mt_c*((480*x[0]*pow(x[2],2))/pow(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2),2)-(35*pow(x[2],4)*(32*pow(x[0],3)+32*x[0]*pow(x[1],2)+32*x[0]*pow(x[2],2)))/pow(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4),2))*pow(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2),2))/pow(R_t,5)-(1.5*G*mt_c*x[0]*((35*pow(x[2],4))/(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4))-(30*pow(x[2],2))/(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2))+0.3750)*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/pow(R_t,5)-(6*G*mt_c*x[0]*pow(x[2],2)*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/(pow(R_t,3)*pow(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2),2)));

    torus_force_r[1]=((G*mt_c*x[1]*((3*pow(x[2],2))/(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2))-0.5))/pow(R_t,3)-(0.3750*G*mt_c*((480*x[1]*pow(x[2],2))/pow(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2),2)-(35*pow(x[2],4)*(32*pow(x[0],2)*x[1]+32*pow(x[1],3)+32*x[1]*pow(x[2],2)))/pow(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4),2))*pow(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2),2))/pow(R_t,5)-(1.5*G*mt_c*x[1]*((35*pow(x[2],4))/(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4))-(30*pow(x[2],2))/(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2))+0.3750)*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/pow(R_t,5)-(6*G*mt_c*x[1]*pow(x[2],2)*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/(pow(R_t,3)*pow(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2),2)));

    torus_force_r[2]=((G*mt_c*x[2]*((3*pow(x[2],2))/(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2))-0.5))/pow(R_t,3)+(0.3750*G*mt_c*pow(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2),2)*((60*x[2])/(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2))-(480*pow(x[2],3))/pow(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2),2)-(140*pow(x[2],3))/(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4))+(35*pow(x[2],4)*(32*pow(x[0],2)*x[2]+32*pow(x[1],2)*x[2]+32*pow(x[2],3)))/pow(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4),2)))/pow(R_t,5)+(0.5*G*mt_c*((6*x[2])/(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2))-(12*pow(x[2],3))/pow(2*pow(x[0],2)+2*pow(x[1],2)+2*pow(x[2],2),2))*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/pow(R_t,3)-(1.5*G*mt_c*x[2]*((35*pow(x[2],4))/(8*pow(x[0],4)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[1],2)+16*pow(x[0],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[1],4)+16*pow(x[1],2)*pow(x[2],2)+8*pow(x[2],4))-(30*pow(x[2],2))/(8*pow(x[0],2)+8*pow(x[1],2)+8*pow(x[2],2))+0.3750)*(pow(x[0],2)+pow(x[1],2)+pow(x[2],2)))/pow(R_t,5));    

for (int ind=0;ind<3;ind++)
    {
        h_force=...;
        a[ind]=t_force[ind]+h_force;

    }
}


//Calculating force for every particle, for setting up initial conditions
void force(double x[3], double a[3])
{
    //Norms
    double md=norm(x);
    //Forces
    double h_force;
    for (int ind=0;ind<3;ind++)
    {
        h_force=...;
        a[ind]=h_force;
    }
    
}

// Assigning velocities to particles 
void initial_cond(double x[3],double v[3], double a[3])
{
    //Norms
    double md=norm(x);
    double phi=atan2(x[1],x[0]);
    //Forces
    force(x,a);
    v[0]=sqrt(norm(a)*md)*cos(phi+pi/2);
    v[1]=sqrt(norm(a)*md)*sin(phi+pi/2);
    v[2]=0;
}


//'Kick' part of a Leapfrog integrator
void kick(double x[3], double v[3], double a[3], double dt, double t)
{ 
    calculate_force(x, a, t);
    for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        v[k]+=a[k]*dt/2.;
    }
}
//'Drift' part of Leapfrog integrator
void drift(double x[3], double v[3], double dt)
{
    for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
         x[k]+=v[k]*dt;
    }
}

// Function to save particles positions/velocities/energy/etc to a file
void snapshot( char nom[999], int snapshot,char *n1, char *n2, char *n3, double x[pno][3], double v[pno][3],double mt_c)
{
    FILE *fill;
    char NAM[999];
    sprintf(NAM, "%s_%.12s_%.12s_%.12s.%06d.dat", nom,n1,n2,n3,snapshot);
    fill = fopen(NAM,"w");    
    fprintf(fill,"%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\n", 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    for (int j=0;j<pno;j++)
            {
            fprintf(fill,"%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\t%.16f\n", x[j][0],x[j][1],x[j][2],v[j][0],v[j][1],v[j][2],
                calculate_erg(x[j],v[j],mt_c));
            }
    fclose(fill);

}
/////////////////////Finished defining functions/////////////////////

//Core of code
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    //Setting coordinates and velocities, prior to launch
    double t, mt_c;
    double mt_c;
    int step=1;

    // Coordinates, velocities, and accelerations of toy particles
    static double x[pno][3];
    static double v[pno][3];
    static double a[pno][3];

    // Loading particle coordinates from .IC file, getting the initial velocities and writing them into the aformentioned arrays
    FILE *f1;
    char IC[999];
    sprintf(IC,"NFW.IC");
    char output_H[9];
    char output_TM[9];
    char output_TR[9];
    f1 = fopen(IC,"r");    
    for (int j=0;j<pno;j++)
    {
        fscanf(f1,"%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", &x[j][0],&x[j][1],&x[j][2]);
        initial_cond(x[j],v[j],a[j]);
        // Rotating the coordiantes and velocities, my test requires a tilted disc of toy particles
        rotate(x[j],v[j],pi/2-theta);
    }

    // Writing down simulation parameters for filenames
    snprintf(output_H,9,"%f",log10(Mh));
    snprintf(output_TM,9,"%f",log10(Mt_f));
    snprintf(output_TR,9,"%f",log10(R_t));

    // Setting initial mass of t_force potential to 0, saving the particles as an "initial conditions" file
    mt_c=0;
    snapshot(name,0,output_H,output_TM,output_TR,x,v,mt_c);

    // Main orbit integration
    // Prior to this it was a while-loop but from previous work in Python
    // I was cautious it would slow computation
    for (int k=0;k<timelim;k+=1)
    {
        // Get current simulation time and t_force mass to use in force calculations
        t=k*dt;
        mt_c=Mt(t);

        // Leapfrog integrator loop
        // Prior to this version, I added a "#pragma omp parallel for" but it only slowed the code down
        for (int j=0;j<pno;j++)
        {
            kick(x[j],v[j],a[j],dt,mt_c);
            drift(x[j],v[j],dt);
            kick(x[j],v[j],a[j],dt,mt_c);
        }

        // When time meets the condition below - save snapshot. 
        // I am cautious that this is a bottleneck, but many runs were inconclusive
        if (t>CCD*step)
        {   
            snapshot(name,step,output_H,output_TM,output_TR,x,v,mt_c);
            step+=1;
        }

    }

}


"any methods of optimising it?" Enabling the optimizer would be a start. You don't mention how you compile this and if the optimizer is disabled, all discussions about performance are nonsense.

@Lundin my bad, I wasn't aware of that, which again shows how much I know about C coding. I compile it with gcc-13. How do I enable the optimizer?

@Lundin also what did you mean by "nonsense"? You're saying that enabling an optimizer would be enough that any small changes to how I define functions etc. would be marginal in comparison? Just trying to understand, cheers.

@Tigs Yes. You're minimal changes are generally not going to make a difference, as the optimizer is most likely going to do them for you. Use -O2 or -O3 to enable them. You can't generally ask for performance advice on which is better, as the only real answer to any performance issue is to measure and compare. -O3 tries to optimize harder, but can make the binary larger.

"Are while-loops are slower than for-loops?" no. Why not bench mark this though? What would a 'buffer' do that a double array doesn't? You're still going to need to store N double values in memory?

If optimizations are disabled, the compiler does not attempt to generate the fastest possible code, as simple as that. It's like measuring how fast a car can go by driving a different car and in traffic, stopping for red lights now and then. That is: nonsense, there's no relation between the two cars what so ever.

@matt I tried to, but it didn't prove anything for me, which made me believe there's other clutter that's not giving a proper answer to this question. But I'm glad that it's not true, because realistically I want my timestep to be dynamic, i.e. dependant on the simulation. About the buffer, I am unsure, it's just an uneducated thought as I'd rather not interrupt the loop computations with saving a file and instead leave it for later, like 5000 loop steps later. At least I don't want to ask the code to constantly if-check the time value, that has to be a bottleneck, right?

@Lundin OK, understood, thank you, I will test the different optimization flags. I will try to answer my question once I run enough benchmarks or someone spots some other erroneous bit of my code.

@TedKleinBergman Understood, I will start benchmarking, thank you.

Benchmarking is a complex topic. Most often it is much more complex than the actual program written. And some 90% (I'm not exaggerating) of "bad performance" questions here on SO could be explained by incorrect benchmarking. So if you weren't until now even aware of the -O flags of your compiler, that would suggest that your chances of performing correct benchmarking of this are very slim. It is very system specific and x86 targets are particularly difficult due to the complex cache handling and multicore. Plus the mainstream OS for x86 aren't real-time OS.

" but it didn't prove anything for me" true, that is often the case with a try it and see. You don't prove something, but it does give you an idea and in this case it is not relevant to your problem. An "if check" is very fast. If you're iterating over 1e6 particles and performing numerous calculations on each one, then a single if check outside of that loop is not going to be noticable.

Side note: given you're relatively inexperienced in C, I suggest you perform several test-runs with address and UB sanitizers on (even for short datasets); those may find bugs of a class that might manifest in ugly ways once your code is optimized.

Edit the question to provide a [mre]. In the places marked ..., one of two things is true: Either the elided code has a substantial computational burden on the program and should not have been elided for the question or it has a slight burden and can be replaced by simple demonstration code, such as setting the relevant values to constants, maybe zeros.

t+=dt at the end of your loop does nothing (that's not the cause of your slowdown, just wanted to note it as it is misleading)

@Lundin that's an insane statistic, noted. But I will still try to do rudimentary tests i.e. if it at least runs faster with the same output. The way this code is right now is the most basic scenario, I will need to add more things, like particle-particle interactions, so I'd rather start learning to benchmark somehow (with proper reading, of course)

@alagner Thank you I will check that, I am cautious that there might be some bugs that I am unaware of related to memory storage/accessing. That's something I know even less about when it comes to C.

@julaine thanks, that's a relic of the old code when it was a while-loop and the time had to be updated.

@EricPostpischil makes sense, I will add it now. My initial reasoning for excluding it is because it's bulky, but also there's nothing much I can do to minimise it math-wise (It's an annoying potential with ugly derivatives). Please let me know if it seems to be a contributing factor to the slowdown.

Does your optimizations-turned-on-code run faster with openmp? This problem is emberassingly parallel and if OpenMP makes it slower there is something going wrong (false sharing, too small block-size etc)

The memory-layout of your particles is also a front I would attack if you have time for large refactoring. Saving each particle as three consecutive memory locations is not ideal, as it forbids SIMD-operations. Flip it on its head and use x[3][pno]. and then always work on multiple particles at a time. Hard work though, try other things first.

Thinking about it, I am pretty sure false sharing is the reason openmp made your code slower. Read up on the phenomenon (and caches in general)

@julaine I haven't tested that yet, but will check. My previous tests have been unsuccessful with marginal or no improvements. Should've taken the hint that there's a deeper issue. I assumed based on the task that it would be  emberassingly parallel, but my lack of knowledge in openmp/data sharing resulted in a very simple attempt - I added #pragma omp parallel for to my main leapfrog integrator loop. I'd be thankful for any basic suggestions for my code in regards of parallelisation so I can move in the right direction.

The basic trouble of 'false sharing' is: writing to memory-location x[7] makes it so that if another thread has to obtain x[8], they have to get it from the (slow) RAM instead of the (fast) cpu-cache.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Tigs Gien, aside:  #define G 0.00449857598201285, what is the source of that value?  Does not appear to be G.

Still no [mre], so I voted to close.

@chux-ReinstateMonica it is G, but in very specific units - pc^3 * Msol^-1 * Myr^-2

As pointed by EricPostpischil, the code is not reproducible : mt_c is declared twice, h_force=...; does not compile, torus_force_r is undefined, headers are missing as well as the exact command line. Not to mention profiling details are missing as well as the input file. As of now, answers can just make guesses (so be possibly wrong) and this is what happened... Please fix this if you want help.

I tried to fix errors myself and remove the part not compiling. I cannot reproduce the issue on my machine (i5-9600KF CPU) : OpenMP results in a significant speed up (with both -O0 and -O2 using GCC 13.2 on Linux). Using -O2 significantly improve performance as expected. I guess there is a race condition slowing down your code but the code you provide is obviously not the one you run so the modified part is certainly the culprit. This is why minimal reproducible codes and profiling details are so important ;) .

You ware sweating the small stuff by worrying about if constructs and the differences between loop types.  C is not a complicated language and it is compiles, so all those control-flow constructs are translated by the compiler to simple machine instructions.
Rather your code is dominated by three things that affect performance:

The sheer amount of data processed.
The many complex math expressions and math library function calls you are processing.
The filesystem in your of your main loop.

That last one is dominant, and no amount of compiler optimisation will make your filesystem run faster, and even on a SSD with caching etc. the file I/O will be orders of magnitude slower than RAM access. I would bet you will see the most significant increase in performance if you could factor out the file I/O in "snapshot".
Not just the file I/O but also the use of formatted I/O (e.g. fprintf()) which is in turn much slow even without the file I/O.  That is true of any code application regardless of language used.  In this case the fprintf() is iterated 1000000 times each time you call snapshot.  Have you tested that on its own to determine how long it takes.
Test without the snapshot() - nothing appears to read that data in any case so it is completely unnecessary.  If you do need that data, buffer it in memory and dump it far less frequently (or not at all if it is simply used elsewhere in the same application), or use a memory-mapped file if the data needs to be persistent (exist after termination).

I am worried that a 20 x 1000000 x 7 double array would be too massive to be computational efficient.

Not as inefficient as file I/O!  140MB is not that large unless you are running in a 30 year old PC!  DDR4 RAM has a transfer rate of >17GB/s, DDR5 double that.  Again you are sweating the small stuff.  Generally in PC applications throwing memory at a problem speeds it up as you avoid having to use far slower mass storage (filesystem) - right up to the point where you are using so much that the OS uses the filesystem (swapfile) for you.  Bit even with memory swapping, that will still be faster that doing your own file I/O at the application level.  A memory mapped file uses the same techniques the OS uses for its swapfile, so is faster than the stdio interface if you really need file I/O.

Looking at process statistics should be able to tell whether significant time is being spent waiting for I/O completion.

The program does not perform filesystem access on every iteration of the main loop. It writes when t exceeds CCD*step, where step is advanced by 1 after each output and CCD is 1. t is advanced by dt = .001 each iteration, so snapshot is called once out of every thousand iterations.

@EricPostpischil yes I did not take the time to analyse that far.  Nonetheless snapshot performs a loop of 1000000 fprintf calls.  It will take significant time even If called just once.

@EricPostpischil :  modified.

Your kick/drift/kick loop is data parallel, so by making it OpenMP parallel you should get many factors of improvement, basically your number of cores, or slightly below.
However, since you gave no details on the OpenMP settings I can just guess.

Set OMP_NUM_THREADS first one, then two, and gradually up to the number of cores.
Set OMP_PROC_BIND=true.
No further settings in your code.
Your snapshot opens a file. Do this only very sparely because it is very slow. At first remove this statement and see if OpenMP on the time integrator  gives speedup.

